# How to remove timezone when convert from Date to DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, time, jodatime

I have a Date get from Database  and I want convert it to DateTime and set it to begin day. I write it below:

```
Date fromDate = studentDateJoin.getDate();
//result: fromDate = Mon Jan 01 00:00:02 ICT 2018
//convert to DateTime 
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(fromDate);
```

But when I convert it add time zone after convert. newDate look like :

```
newDate = 2018-01-01T14:13:04.574Z+7
```

I have a question: How to convert it to begin day and remove timezone: Example I want to convert it look like:

```
 //Convert it begin day and remove time zone
 newDate = 2018-01-01T00:00:00.00;
```

How to convert it to beginDay and remove timezone: Thankyou

Comment: There is no `DateTime` class in Java 8, though there is a [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) in the Joda-Time library. Did you mean to write `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry because i working two DateTime and wrong it. Thank you I had edit. So could you please help me ?

Comment: If you want it to look like `2018-01-01T00:00:00.00Z`, with a `Z` at the end, then it is not a `LocalDateTime`, but an `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: new LocalDateTime(fromDate) DOES NOT exist in Java......

Comment: I want only remove TimeZone and setIt to begin day

Comment: I had fix it from post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Added Joda-Time version, since question was changed from `java-8` to `jodatime`.

---

If you have a Joda-Time `DateTime`, then use [`toLocalDate()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toLocalDate()) and [`toLocalDateTime(...)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toLocalDateTime(org.joda.time.LocalTime)):

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1, 14, 13, 04, 574);
System.out.println(dateTime);
LocalDate localDate = dateTime.toLocalDate();
System.out.println(localDate);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = localDate.toLocalDateTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
System.out.println(localDateTime);
```

```
2018-01-01T14:13:04.574-05:00
2018-01-01
2018-01-01T00:00:00.000
```

---

If you have "a Date get from Database", i.e. a `java.sql.Date`, then use [`toLocalDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--) and [`atStartOfDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--):

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(118, 0, 1);
System.out.println(sqlDate);
LocalDate localDate = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
System.out.println(localDate);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay();
System.out.println(localDateTime);
```

```
2018-01-01
2018-01-01
2018-01-01T00:00
```

---

If you have a `java.sql.Timestamp`, use [`toLocalDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toLocalDateTime--) and [`truncatedTo(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-):

```
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(118, 0, 1, 14, 13, 04, 574000000);
System.out.println(sqlTimestamp);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(localDateTime);
localDateTime = localDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
System.out.println(localDateTime);
```

```
2018-01-01 14:13:04.574
2018-01-01T14:13:04.574
2018-01-01T00:00
```

---

If you have a `java.util.Date`, use [`toInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--), [`atZone(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-), [`toLocalDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDate--), and [`atStartOfDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--):

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(118, 0, 1, 14, 13, 04);
System.out.println(utilDate);
Instant instant = utilDate.toInstant();
System.out.println(instant);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = zonedDateTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay();
System.out.println(localDateTime);
```

```
Mon Jan 01 14:13:04 EST 2018
2018-01-01T19:13:04Z
2018-01-01T14:13:04-05:00[America/New_York]
2018-01-01T00:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have question. How to input "Mon Jan 01 00:00:02 ICT 2018" it into java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date("Mon Jan 01 00:00:02 ICT 2018"); . I had input it but it can't convert.

Comment: @tbtrungit `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse("Mon Jan 01 00:00:02 ICT 2018")`

Comment: If I had 2018-01-01T14:13:04-05:00[America/New_York] how to I remove timezone and result looklike 2018-01-01T00:00:00?

Comment: @tbtrungit `ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-01-01T14:13:04-05:00[America/New_York]").toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()`

Comment: If ""2018-01-01T14:13:04-05:00[America/New_York]" not String and 2018-01-01T14:13:04-05:00[America/New_York] is DateTime. I don't need parse and just only using :

**//Result is : 2018-01-01T14:13:04-05:00[America/New_York]**
`DateTime dateTime = result.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()` ?

Comment: @tbtrungit There is no `DateTime` class in Java 8. Since your question is tagged `java-8` and is not tagged `jodatime`, this answer is for the Java 8 Time API. If you want to know how to do all this using Joda-Time, you need to edit the question and clarify that. If you need to convert between Joda-Time and Java 8 Time, that's an entirely different question, which has already been answered, so do a search for those answers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had edit question. Sorry for unclear question.