# New Date() object changes format when switching timezones

Tags: android, date, kotlin, timezone

I'm working with an application that routinely creates a new `Date()` object every few seconds from a location object:

```
val logDate = Date(location.time).toString()
Log.d("test", "$logDate")
```

Every few seconds, the date will be logged to the console:

> D/test: Wed Jul 22 12:02:14 MDT 2020
>
> D/test: Wed Jul 22 12:02:19 MDT 2020

If I then go into the Date & time settings on my device and manually change the timezone to Buenos Aires, the following will start to print:

> D/test: Wed Jul 22 15:02:24 GMT-03:00 2020
>
> D/test: Wed Jul 22 15:02:35 GMT-03:00 2020

Notice the addition of "GMT-03:00". This change in format results in various parsing related exceptions deeper in the application due to the format change.

**Questions:**

1. Why does the format change after switching the timezone?
2. Is there a way to ensure only one format is used?

Thanks!

Comment: Explicitly format the string? I'm a fan of ISO8601, and..

Comment: use Calendar instead

Comment: @user2864740 ISO8601 is being used elsewhere. That's not the problem, and isn't related to the questions posted as the questions are specifically related to the construction of a date via `Date()` and the format a representation of that date takes by default. Funny enough, there are cases where the String representation of `Date()` is not accepted as a valid format for its own constructor, `Date(s: String)`.

Comment: @Style-7 I appreciate the comment, but swapping implementations doesn't resolve the question.

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat

Comment: @Orbit The problem would be non-existent with an explicit ISO8601 (or probably any explicit date format that explicitly requested an offset [only], see the Calendar type). The location of this deviation appears to be related with the ability to resolve a TZ or not. The Date itself doesn't "have" a format: the `toString()` method of it does.

Comment: @Orbit Specifically, a case like AST (for Argentina Standard Time) is ambiguous: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations; even without being explicitly included in said "common" list.. would have to reference that with the specific TZ/mapping list used. GMT-03:00 is not ambiguous, although it does lose the TZ designator. Again, back to the very original comment which was written with thought.

Comment: @user2864740 The problem is that if this String is persisted in a database and then used again to create a `Date` object, a parse error will be thrown with the version that uses the `GMT-06:00` format. It's weird that the String version of the `Date` can't be used when creating a date via the constructor that takes a String `Date(s: String)`. Why is that (apparently) not considered a bug with either the `toString()` method or the constructor?

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the parsing. The switch to GMT+offset is expected (as explained by the ambiguity; its actually more restrictive than that..). Do these strings parse if using “GMT+0300” instead of “GMT+03:00”? It is expected that they will parse using the former. If so, switch to using an string formatting that always emits “GMT+hhmm” will resolve the issue, as well as using a format like ISO8601..

Comment: See Date.formar (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date) which briefly alludes to acceptable formats and shows an example of the GMT+hhmm form only. Also note the very old deprecation status of these methods. Switching from to DateFormat.parse might just “work” (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat), or maybe it’ll be the same issue *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "GMT-03:00" isn't an addition, is a substitution for "MDT" (Mountain Date Time). The Timezone was specified in both outputs you shared.

You may use JodaTime library as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52299342/10860780) from [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) to avoid the TimeZone, or use SimpleDateFormat as [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9057721/style-7) replied.

Comment: The problem is that the `Date(s: String)` constructor does not accept it's own format (when "GMT-03:00" is used). So in my example, `Date()` as a String spits out `Wed Jul 22 15:02:24 GMT-03:00 2020`, which is then stored in a database. When that same String is then retrieved and used to recreate a `Date` object, passing that String into the constructor will result in a parse error. This seems incredibly strange, and something I would normally report as a bug. Is this expected behavior for the Date() class? If so, why?

Comment: It’s fine for the output to use a GMT offset - https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date

Comment: @Orbit You should store your `Date` as a `Date` or as a `long` in database. Parse the `Date` to a `String` when displaying it in UI. The only non-deprecated method for instanciating a `Date()` object is `public Date(long date)`, the `long` stands for time in milliseconds, which is the most precise.